# Select data between two dates?

Tags: php, mysql, select, date

I'm using a database to store logs, with a column "date" which holds the date it was inserted. The format of the date is "MM/DD/YY". Please can anyone suggest how I would SELECT data in between two certain dates. For example, I tried this:

```
$from_date = "01/01/12";
$to_date = "02/11/12";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logs WHERE date >= " . $from_date . " AND date <= " . $to_date . " ORDER by id DESC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
// display results here
}
```

But I guess this doesn't work because the dates aren't numbers. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: it will work. you have to put to `date('')` your parameters  or `date '$param'` or `str_to_date()` or `convert('$param','%y/%m/%d')`....

Comment: Have you considered using a real Date column or change the format to `YY/MM/DD`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the `BETWEEN` keyword:

```
"SELECT * FROM logs WHERE date BETWEEN '" . $from_date . "' AND  '" . $to_date . "'
ORDER by id DESC"
```

Comment: What if i have to find two date between two dates.. like SELECT * FROM logs WHERE date1 AND date2 BETWEEN '" . $from_date . "' AND  '" . $to_date . "'
@Sarfraz

Answer (score 3):

You can cast the fields as dates and then select between from_date and to_date

```
SELECT * FROM logs WHERE date STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m/%d/%Y') between STR_TO_DATE(from_date, '%m/%d/%Y') and STR_TO_DATE(to_date, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question depends on the data type that is used to store the `date` field in the `logs` table.

SQL (MySQL in your case) is fully capable of comparing dates. Usually, the `BETWEEN .. AND ..` operator is used but that will not work correctly if the type of `date` is CHAR (or VARCHAR) - in which case you will need to cast the `date` field to a DATETIME before comparing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add single quotes to the date values '01/01/12':

```
$from_date = "01/01/12";
$to_date = "02/11/12";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logs WHERE date >= '" . $from_date . "' AND date <= '" . $to_date . "' ORDER by id DESC");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change date parameters into Unix timestamps and then compare them. Here is the code:

```
$from_date = "2019/01/12";
$to_date = "2019/01/15";

$from_date_unix = strtotime($from_date);
$to_date_unix = strtotime($to_date);    

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logs WHERE date >= " . $from_date_unix . " AND date <= " . $to_date_unix . " ORDER by id DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
// display results here
}
```