# Select records of a given date that are within a certain time interval

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field, session_date that is stored as datetime in a MySql database.

I want to select records from a given date that are between two time intervals.

```
.[..]WHERE DATE_ADD(o.session_date, INTERVAL o.session_date HOUR_SECOND)
BETWEEN '2010-01-01 16:30:00' AND '2010-01-02 17:00:00'
```

Something like that?

UPDATE:  this is for a mysql query.

Comment: I see you are using PHP, but what type of database are you trying to query? Specifying the style of SQL the database uses will result in a clearer question and hopefully a better answer.

Comment: this is for a mysql query

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232122/select-data-between-two-dates