# how do I compare date and display record only if its in todays and before expiry

Tags: php, mysql, date-comparison

I want to display database records only if `testfrom` date is `todays` and `testto` date is not over.

The following code I tried below does not seem to be working well, could someone have a look what am I doing wrong?

the stored date value in the database is

```
testfrom - 2017-02-23 00:00:00
testto - 2017-02-24 23:59:59
```

my code

```
    $dt = date("Y-m-d");
    $srt = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($r['testfrom']));
    $end = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($r['testto']));
 if($srt >= $dt || $end <= $dt){

    }
```

is this the right way?

Appreciate your valuable time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select data between two dates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232122/select-data-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your condition like this:

```
 $dt = date("Y-m-d");
    $srt = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2017-02-23 00:00:00"));
    $end = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2017-02-24 23:59:59"));
 if($srt == $dt && $end >= $dt){
  echo "yes";
    }
```